# Can I use requests.post to submit a form?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the list of stores from this site:
http://www.health.state.mn.us/divs/cfh/wic/wicstores/

I'd like to get the list of stores that is produced when you click on the button "View All Stores". I understand that I *could* use Selenium or MechanicalSoup or ... to do this but I was hoping to use requests.

It looks like clicking on the button submits a form:

```
 <form name="setAllStores" id="setAllStores" action="/divs/cfh/wic/wicstores/index.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checksetAllStores(this)">
<input name="submitAllStores" id="submitAllStores"  type="submit" value="View All Stores" />
```

But I have no idea how to write the requests query (or indeed if this is even possible).

Why I have tried so far is variations on:

```
SITE = 'http://www.health.state.mn.us/divs/cfh/wic/wicstores/'
data = {'name': 'setAllStores', 'form': 'submitAllStores', 'input': 'submitAllStores'}
r = requests.post(SITE, data)
```

But this doesn't work.  Any help / advice would be welcome.

Comment: Try writing `requests.post(SITE, payloads = data)` hopefully this will solve your issue

Comment: 1) use the url in the form's action attribute, 2) post this data `{'submitAllStores': 'View All Stores'}`

Comment: Actually, the url should be fine, just change your post data.

Comment: Thanks t.m. adam.  That did the trick.  If you had two minutes, I would learn a lot if you could explain where I was going wrong.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, in your `data` dict you should have the names and values of the form inputs. The form 'action' is where the form gets submitted. If you have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below code to populate the result, if you considered to select `view all stores` option.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

FormData={
    'submitAllStores':'View All Stores'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.post("http://www.health.state.mn.us/divs/cfh/wic/wicstores/index.cfm",data=FormData)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    for item in soup.select(".info"):
        shopname = item.select_one(".info-service").text
        print(shopname)
```

Partial output:

```
1st Quality Market
33rd Meat & Grocery
52 Market  And Trading
75 Market And Deli
7th Grocery
9th Ave X-Press
```