# why did I fail to try the post using requests.post?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I know this post may Duplicate from other questions,but i have read any post and do not get what i want to know

I have read this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592572/can-i-use-requests-post-to-submit-a-form) before i ask this.

## My problem

I want to scrape [This page](https://www.resi.co.id) with `BeautifulSoup` and `requests.post` to submit some form from web.

And this example code i used:

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://www.resi.co.id"
datas = {
    "userForm":{
           "id":"80879880999985"
     }
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    req = s.post(url, data=json.dumps(datas)
    if req.ok:
        soups = BS(req.text,"html.parser")
        print(soups.prettify())
```

I think i can see output what i want,but no one results i want from output,Where my wrong? I just read and try any examples from google and post from stackoverflow but i didn't getting anything what i want.

I really appreciate every help, and sorry for my English.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I think this will output some tag from table like This [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/X8FySFF)

Comment: @katrocoplax what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: Only source from html tag,but not what i want, i think this will have some tag from table tag like [This](https://ibb.co/X8FySFF) but i didn't see them @DevanshuMisra

Comment: @katrocoplax you are unable to see the desired result because the data you pass(i.e. the `id` in your url) is invalid. And because of that it does not return you the data, the way you want it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite entirely sure what you want as it's not clear. But, to get the data, you need to include those in your `datas`. Also the request url is `https://api1.cekresi.co.id/allcnote.php`. It'll return html/text, not json. And then you can use pandas to just grab those tables:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://api1.cekresi.co.id/allcnote.php"
datas = {"id":"070950000307119",
         'kurir': 'jne'}


with requests.Session() as s:
    req = s.post(url, data=datas)
    if req.ok:
        tables = pd.read_html(req.text)

        for table in tables:
            print (table)
            print ('\n')
```

**Output:**

```
                 0  1                        2
0          No Resi  :          070950000307119
1           Status  :                DELIVERED
2          Service  :                    YES19
3  Dikirim tanggal  :               2019-02-09
4     Dikirim oleh  :        JESAND SHOPBEKASI
5       Dikirim ke  :  EDWINPINANG , TANGERANG
6       JNE Status  :                DELIVERED


                   0                        ...                                                                          2
0            Tanggal                        ...                                                                 Keterangan
1   2019-02-09 14:07                        ...                          SHIPMENT RECEIVED BY JNE COUNTER OFFICER AT [B...
2   2019-02-09 17:08                        ...                                 SHIPMENT PICKED UP BY JNE COURIER [BEKASI]
3   2019-02-09 17:14                        ...                                        RECEIVED AT SORTING CENTER [BEKASI]
4   2019-02-09 19:46                        ...                                       PROCESSED AT SORTING CENTER [BEKASI]
5   2019-02-10 03:50                        ...                                          RECEIVED AT WAREHOUSE [TANGERANG]
6   2019-02-10 05:33                        ...                          SHIPMENT FORWARDED TO DESTINATION [TANGERANG, ...
7   2019-02-10 12:42                        ...                                                      RUMAH / KANTOR KOSONG
8   2019-02-10 12:42                        ...                                          WITH DELIVERY COURIER [TANGERANG]
9   2019-02-11 10:32                        ...                                          WITH DELIVERY COURIER [TANGERANG]
10  2019-02-11 13:40                        ...                                             ALAMAT TIDAK LENGKAP / TIDAK D
11  2019-02-11 15:10                        ...                                          WITH DELIVERY COURIER [TANGERANG]
12  2019-02-11 15:32                        ...                          DELIVERED TO [EDWIN | 11-02-2019 15:32 | TANGE...

[13 rows x 3 columns]


            0                   1           2
0     Tanggal              Lokasi  Keterangan
1  2019-02-09  PINANG , TANGERANG   DELIVERED
```